# How to get name exports across when migrating from Webpack 4 to 5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm attempting to migrate a React Hook library from Webpack 4 to version 5. The problem I'm facing is that after updating the package.json dependencies and building the package without errors I keep getting TypeError: (0 , *intc_use_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.useMyAPP) is not a function.
Here is my webpack config file that works on version 4

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: '',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This is my current Webpack 5 configuration file after many attempts to simplify it.

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  externalsPresets: { node: true },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: {
      type: 'commonjs',
    },
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Also this is how I do my name exports (which work on version 4)
export { apiMessStore, useMyAPP, ApiMessProvider};

I would appreciate if anyone has an idea of what I'm missing in this upgrade process